# Download webpage with JavaScript by webpage c#

Tags: c#, javascript, download, webclient

I want to download a webpage after or with his JavaScript. For example a webpage with data that load in javaScript. I'm using WebClient class.

My code:

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
htmlDoc = wb.DownloadString(link);
```

My problem is that I get the html code before the data is downloaded by the javaScript.
What can I do?

Here is my link: http://www.select-test.com/HTML/frmDisplayGrid.aspx?Type=cat&Data=OS

thanks, 
Chani

Comment: Simply parsing for the JavaScript after it has downloaded is not an option?

Comment: An option could be to either replace the relative paths to absolute, or even shorter add a **<base>** tag, which would cause the page to load as if it was at that location.

Comment: The question is not how or what to do to the webPage, it is how to write my code in c#